# cURL PHP API client

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to access the following API:

```
https://image.ibb.co/nabzZw/segmentify_api.jpg
```

My code is as follows but it's not working:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://panel-api.segmentify.com/getToken");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"username\":\"XXXXX\",\"password\":\"YYYYYYY\"};");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

What the solution might be?

Comment: You could try to `echo curl_error($ch);` right after your `curl_exec` to have a hint about the error.

Comment: Error:SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: So I guess you could either find the curl setting to disable the SSL check (pro hint: not good for production code) or remove the self-signed certificate / set up a not self-signed one.

Comment: I think the problem was caused by the localserver settings.. i tested the same code on an online server and it's working!

Comment: Yes, most likely the online server has a proper SSL cert, so you don't get the error as in the local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're sending an invalid json,

replace `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"username\":\"XXXXX\",\"password\":\"YYYYYYY\"};");`
   with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
        'username'=>'XXXXX',
        'password'=>'YYYYYYYYY'         
)));
```

and it won't happen again. (but your real error is that semicolon at the end, that's not allowed in json. it's legal javascript though. still, having PHP generate the json for you is much safer than hand-crafting json strings, as you have just experienced fist-hand.)